# Nonce count values received from Firefox version>63 confuse our web server during digest authentication

Tags: firefox, webserver, digest-authentication, nonce

I am experiencing an unexpected behavior of Firefox browser interacting with a web server I am working on. The scenario in question involves digest-based authentication. The problem is that in subsequent queries received from Firefox contain nonce count increased by 2 instead of 1. As a result, our web server rejects the browser's request and forces another authentication.
We do not observe similar browser behavior with Chrome, nor Firefox earlier than version 63.
Do you have any hints what could cause Firefox to increase nonce count by values larger than 1?
We have also tested Firefox against apache server setup with digest authentication and the exchange between both parties looks ok.
Also, maybe our web server should not reject accept nonce count values increased by 2?

Comment: Did you see anything suspicious in wireshark and/or browser console logs?

Comment: No, there is nothing suspicious in logs. No additional msgs with nc =2 which could be missed by our server.